# redirecting to url in perl web development

Tags: apache, perl

I am trying to redirect to another url in my perl web application using CGI::Session.:

```
sub redirect_to {
    my ($self, $url) = @_;
    $self->{session}->redirect("http://google.com");
}
```

But was this does, is that it appends informational text and a link to the url:

> Found
>
> The document has moved here.

How do i force it to load the url? Is this an apache configuration issue or a perl issuue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a problem in your code. The redirect instruction needs to be sent in place of the usual headers. I'm guessing that you have already sent the header before you call this subroutine.

It's important to know what you want to send, before sending any of it.